# How to detach an attachment for POP3 using ruby net/pop?

Tags: ruby, pop3, email-attachments

```
    pop = Net::POP3.new mailhost
    pop.start mailuser, mailpass

    if pop.mails.empty?

      puts "Mailbox empty."

    else

      pop.mails.each do |mail|    
        if mail.pop.has_attachments?
            mail.pop.attachments.each do |attachment|
              puts attachment.original_filename
            end
        end
      end

    end
```

gives `undefined method 'has_attachments?' for #<String:0xb7cc4f7c>`.

Is [this example](http://swik.net/Rails/Dave+Naffis+-+Rails,+Ruby,+Randomness/Receiving+Emails+and+Attachments+with+Rails/kqnw) no longer working?

Comment: hey @ohho , were you able to get this working? I am working on something simlair and I can do message.head, message.blah and know trying to download attachment into a local directory. TIA.

Answer (score 1):

`mail.pop` returns string representation of email see [corresponding docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/pop/rdoc/Net/POP3.html). If you want to parse it and work with `mail` object you can do it like this:

```
email = Mail.new(mail.pop)
```

I really recommend you to take a look into docs - if you'll have big attachments you can run into memory issues and this thing is explained in docs.